# test results showing 0 tests run

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I am trying to test my code using pytest. I am getting 0 test ran as a result.

```
**test_main.py**

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from .main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_login_page():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code==200
```

```
==================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\sagabarnisa\Demo App
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                            

=================================================================== no tests ran in 0.18s ===================================================================
```

Comment: `test_login_page` would test a route function called `login_page`.  You don't have a function called `login_page`.

Comment: how to do the same?

Comment: For your information, I have a function called login_page in another file